# R: "installing vignettes failed" for linear mixed-effects library (lme4)

Tags: r, vignette

I know very little about R and am currently attempting to run a pre-written R script.

My key issue is that one of the libraries (lme4 - linear mixed-effects library) doesn't seem to be installing.

The script starts with the following dependencies -

```
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/")))
library(rbundler)
bundle('.')
library(lme4)
```

And the output is as follows, with the error occurring at the very end.

```
Loading required package: devtools

Attaching package: ‘rbundler’

The following object is masked from ‘package:devtools’:

    install_version

R_LIBS_USER=~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.0:./.Rbundle
.libPaths() =/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/usr/lib64/R/library/usr/share/R/library
Bundling package /home/jeeves/my_script dependencies into library ./.Rbundle
Downloading lme4_1.1-7.tar.gz from http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-7.tar.gz
Installing package from /tmp/Rtmp3SzgSS/lme4_1.1-7.tar.gz
Installing lme4
'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL '/tmp/Rtmp3SzgSS/lme4'  \
  --library='/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle' --with-keep.source  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'lme4' ...
** package 'lme4' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGE
N_DONT_VECTORIZE -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c external.cpp -o external.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGE
N_DONT_VECTORIZE -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c glmFamily.cpp -o glmFamily.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGE
N_DONT_VECTORIZE -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c mcmcsamp.cpp -o mcmcsamp.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGE
N_DONT_VECTORIZE -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c optimizer.cpp -o optimizer.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGE
N_DONT_VECTORIZE -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c predModule.cpp -o predModule.o
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/RcppEigen/include"  -DNDEBUG -DEIGE
N_DONT_VECTORIZE -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c respModule.cpp -o respModule.o
g++ -m64 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o lme4.so external.o glmFamily.o mcmcsamp.o optimizer.o predModule.o respModule.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/lme4/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'lme4'
    finding HTML links ... done
    Dyestuff                                html  
    GHrule                                  html  
    GQN                                     html  
    GQdk                                    html  
    InstEval                                html  
    NelderMead-class                        html  
    Nelder_Mead                             html  
    Pastes                                  html  
    Penicillin                              html  
    VarCorr                                 html  
    VerbAgg                                 html  
    bootMer                                 html  
    cake                                    html  
    cbpp                                    html  
    confint.merMod                          html  
    devcomp                                 html  
    drop1.merMod                            html  
    dummy                                   html  
    expandDoubleVerts                       html  
    findbars                                html  
    fixef                                   html  
    fortify                                 html  
    getME                                   html  
    glmFamily-class                         html  
    glmFamily                               html  
    glmer                                   html  
    glmer.nb                                html  
    golden-class                            html  
    golden                                  html  
    grouseticks                             html  
    isNested                                html  
    isREML                                  html  
    lmList-class                            html  
    lmList                                  html  
    lmResp-class                            html  
    lmResp                                  html  
    lme4-package                            html  
    lmer                                    html  
    lmerControl                             html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ... done

    merMod-class                            html  
    merPredD-class                          html  
    merPredD                                html  
    mkMerMod                                html  
    mkReTrms                                html  
    mkRespMod                               html  
    mkVarCorr                               html  
    mkdevfun                                html  
    modular                                 html  
    ngrps                                   html  
    nlformula                               html  
    nlmer                                   html  
    nloptwrap                               html  
    nobars                                  html  
    plot.merMod                             html  
    plots.thpr                              html  
    predict.merMod                          html  
    profile-methods                         html  
    pvalues                                 html  
    ranef                                   html  
    rePos-class                             html  
    rePos                                   html  
    refit                                   html  
    refitML                                 html  
    residuals.merMod                        html  
    sigma                                   html  
    simulate.merMod                         html  
    sleepstudy                              html  
    subbars                                 html  
    varianceProf                            html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
   'PLSvGLS.Rnw' 
   'Theory.Rnw' 
   'lmer.Rnw' using 'UTF-8' 
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) : 
  'arg' should be one of "verbatim", "tex", "hide"
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing '/home/jeeves/my_script/.Rbundle/lme4'
Error: Command failed (1)
Execution halted
```

I tried looking up anything related to `match.arg` and where it might be setting an option other than `"verbatim", "tex", "hide"` but had no luck.

Any ideas on what could be the source of the error?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem seems to be that "Theory.Rnw" and "PLSvGLS.Rnw" have `results=hide` (i.e. Sweave format), while `VignetteBuilder` is set to `knitr` (which would like `results="hide"`).  I'm not sure why this discrepancy hasn't triggered any checking or building errors for the developers ...

Comment: PS I don't really understand what the `rbundler` package does -- this is presumably at least slightly related to the problem